# Angular, Webpack5 Module Federation: Not sharing libraries rxjs

Tags: angular, webpack, module, rxjs, federation

Everything working under NX
If I update a observable in mfe(remote), it is working in the scope of this mfe but not in the shell. the reverse happens the same way, in the shell components it works but the value updates are not visible in the remotes. Of course they all access the same library and same service.

I have seen other posts here with problems with shared in module.exports and with rxjs, but none where everything seems to be set up correctly.

**Service**

```
  private _loginTest = new BehaviorSubject<string>('test');
  loginTest$ = this._loginTest.asObservable();
  sendMsg(message: string) {
    this._loginTest.next(message);
  }
```

**Component.ts in shell, same in component.ts remote**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.storageService.loginTest$.subscribe(
    (message) =>{
      this.value = message;
    }
    );
  }
...
  successMsg() {
    this.storageService.sendMsg('test string ' + this.count++);
  }
```

**Update button in both, shell and remote**

```
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="successMsg()"
        >
        Success Message
      </button>
```

**configuration of webpack**

webpack.config.js

**First try**

```
      shared: share({
        '@enosys/auth': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@angular/core': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@angular/common': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@angular/common/http': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@angular/router': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true, },
        '@angular/cdk': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        '@angular/material': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@angular/forms': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
        'rxjs': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', includeSecondaries: true },
        'rxjs/operators': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '~7.8.0', includeSecondaries: true },
        '@libs/storage-client': { singleton: true },
        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
      }),
```

**Second try**

```
      shared: {
        ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
      },
```

Despite being the same service in the same library in both cases, the subcriptions work, but independently from each other.

Any Idea?

The functionality I would expect is that regardless of where the value is changed, the has the same value on all micro frontends and in the shell.

Everything else works correctly, with no other problems with Module Federation.

Comment: The issue probably has to do with how you are injecting the service, not with module federation. Are you using “providedIn: root”?

Comment: Thank you BizzyBob,
yes, of course
`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`

Your input give me a new Idea to check something

Comment: If you inject the same service within different components in the same mfe, do they receive the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as unfortunately happens all too often, in the end the problem was an oversight.
Wrong path in two variables in webpack.config.js tsConfigPath and workspaceRootPath

In shell and in the remotes have been a level to high

```
const tsConfigPath =
  process.env.NX_TSCONFIG_PATH ??
  path.join(__dirname, '../../../tsconfig.base.json');

const workspaceRootPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../');
```